# Display multiple activities on same screen

Tags: android, android-activity

Is it possible to show two activities on the same screen at the same time?
I need each activity to show data that changes with time.

Answer (score 8):

Or maybe you can use [AndroidFragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)

Answer (score 4):

It's late after the question. 
But you should look at [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html)

Inherits from Activity, so you should be able to run this as the parent.

Comment: note to anyone reading this now: ActivityGroup was deprecated in API 13, suggesting Fragments and FragmentManager instead

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is definitely possible. Even when you display a menu or a dialog, that menu/dialog is a separate activity running on top of yours. However, you should avoid doing that as much as possible. It is only useful to display two activities at the same time if one of the activities does not belong to your application (which is the case with menus/dialogs). If both activities come from your own application, you should find a way to merge them into one. This way you use up less memory and less CPU (as there's no overhead of starting a new process).

Comment: I think you have mistaken Activities with Views. It is not possible to have multiple Activities at the same time; Views - yes. Activities are registered in Manifest and can be started one at a time. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: You are right. Sorry for the misinformed answer. My argument to combine the functionality into the same Activity is even stronger now, though :) +1

Comment: so final conclusion is we can not have two simultaneously activities. 
but i can't merge the functionality in same activity also.so
can we use widget as better option ,as my requirement would be fullfilled this way

Comment: Maybe you'd want to use `Service` s? It would be helpful to tell us more about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: no, i do not want to use service. i want to run two activities on single screen,but as discussed it is not posssible. so may be i should use two widgets which are updated dynamically & simultaneously. for example two widgets 1) playing a video 2) showing current market rates . these two widgets are live & active simultaneously. none is related to each other . just like a CNBC news channel current share prices are also shown and at background news are also shown.