# Android dynamically expanding screen - Begin with one diagram and add more. or multiple connected screens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm having difficulty finding out how I could go about implementing some of my course-work.

I want to make an app, based on a client's concept, it's a mind mapping app that allows users to work on a diagram in order to elaborate ideas.

What I would ideally like is a way of starting with one basic diagram, the shape of which is fixed, and being able to add several more 'connecting' diagrams.

Now the diagram part is not a problem, but how could I make this app work with each diagram connecting?

An ideal scenario would be -

- A user can start a "project" [a project consists of one or more linked diagrams]
- The user can work on the initial diagram, adding information.
- The user can then add another diagram to this project, say-by hitting an on screen button.
- The user will then have the new diagram appear on screen, blank and ready to add information.
- **When the user has more than one diagram, I would like the other diagrams within the current project to appear behind the current diagram**
- **I would like the user to be able to *spin* through diagrams and hopefully have a connecting line or lifeline type thing between them**

This may be a bit vague, the stages in **bold** are what I am kind of stuck on.

If someone would be kind enough to point me in the direction of some reading material, tutorials etc on this kind of thing, I would be extremely grateful!

Thanks in advance,

JohnD

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the kind of thing I wanted.

For anybody who is stuck with multiple activities / screens.

[Display multiple activities on same screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513518/android-displaying-multiple-activities-on-same-screen)

**AndroidFragments**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

**ActivityGroup**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html